# Get records who has only one record in foreign table with given condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have contracts and territories table. They share one-to-many relationships
.
I am trying to create a query to get all contracts only in china.  That would basically return me all the contracts records for which there is only one corresponding record in territories table with name 'china'

If possible I would like to do this without group by. Because to simplify the question I have not included other complicated stuff which will eventually be part of this.

*given the following sample data. I would like to get only contract4 as result:*

```
**contracts**       
contract_id name    
1   contract1   
2   contract2   
3   contract3   
4   contract4   

**territories**     
id  contract_id name
1   1   japan
2   1   china
3   1   india
4   2   japan
5   2   china
6   3   india
7   4   china
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question for both tables, along with the expected output.

Comment: Say you have contract5 with no records in territories table (is it possible?); if so, should contract5 be extracted or not?

Comment: That isn’t a Territories table, it's a Contract-Territories table implementing a many-to-many relationship between Contracts and Territories. If it was a table of territories it wouldn’t have two rows each for Japan and India and three for China.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using `join` and `partition`:

```
    select contract_id from
    (select  c.*, t.name countryname ,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.contract_id ORDER BY t.contract_id 
      DESC)  rn
    from contracts c join territories t
    on c.contract_id = t.contract_id 
    ) a
     where rn = 1 and countryname = 'china'
```

Comment: That syntax looks fine for Oracle. By the way, PL/SQL is the programming language - Oracle SQL is called 'Oracle SQL', or 'SQL' for short :)

Answer (score 0):

try like below by using corelated subquery

```
   select c.*,t.* from contracts c join territories t 
    on c.Id = t.contract_id 
    where  exists ( select 1 from territories t1 
                      where t1.contract_id=t.contract_id
                      having count(distinct name)=1

                     ) and t.name='china'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
select c.* from contracts c join territories t 
    on c.Id = t.contract_id 
    where not exists ( select 1 from territories t1 
                      where t1.contract_id=t.contract_id
                      and t1.name <> 'china'

                     ) and t.name='china'
```

Answer (score 0):

If all contracts have a territory, you can simply do:

```
select c.*
from contracts c
where not exists (select 1
                  from territories t
                  where t.contract_id = c.contract_id and
                        t.country <> 'china'
                 );
```

If you can have contracts with no territories, then you need to check that one actually exists:

```
select c.*
from contracts c
where not exists (select 1
                  from territories t
                  where t.contract_id = c.contract_id and
                        t.country <> 'china'
                 ) and
      exists (select 1
              from territories t
              where t.contract_id = c.contract_id and
                    t.country = 'china'
             );
```

If countries are repeated in the `territories` table, then this method does not require any additional work to eliminate duplicates in the result set.